# Make text color the inverse of dynamic background color?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On the website of Palantir.com, the color of the logo (originally black) is always the inverse of the color of the background behind it, even as the background scrolls/changes.

[image]

I'm creating a website via Wordpress and would like to have the same effect. I've tried using "mix-blend-mode: exclusion;", and while similar, doesn't give the *true* effect of a proper color inverse.

How can I do this in CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`mix-blend-mode: difference` with the font color set at white might help.

The difference with white on white is 0 - ie black.

The difference with white on blue is rgb(255, 255, 0) ie yellow.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(white 0 30px, blue 30px 100%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="text">SOME TEXT</div>
</body>
```

There can be problems with grays though - you can end up with gray on gray so it depends a bit on what your underlying image is actually like as to whether this will be satisfactory enough. (One trick is to apply a slight shadow to the text).

Comment: Got it, thank you!